# How to send to background a running process started with sudo?

Tags: terminal, sudo, background-process

I have just installed SLC6 (derived from SL6 derived from RHEL6). I can send a running process to the background by hitting Ctrl-Z in the terminal where it was started. However, I can't do it when I started the command with sudo. It used to work seamlessly in SLC5.

Is there any configuration I could do to allow this ?

EDIT
This is an example of command I try to run :

```
[user@pcald02 ~]$ sudo emacs
^Z^C
```

The Ctrl-Z makes the symbols ^Z appear but nothing else happens. Now I realized that even Ctrl-C is ineffective.

Without sudo :

```
[user@pcald02 ~]$ emacs
^Z
[1]+  Stopped                 emacs
[user@pcald02 ~]$
```

Comment: Since slm says it works for him on RHEL/CentOS6, you might want to update the post with the actual command that you're trying to run, in case it's something specific to that one command.

Comment: For a new command, instead of an existing command, `sudo -b` might do what you want... (It does not work if you want to reattach though... For that screen might be the best option...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing the real problem here is that the command you are trying to run is Emacs.  Running Emacs as root is hardly ever a good idea. Emacs also overrides a number of keystrokes, so `C-z` might not work simply for that reason. If `root` is already logged in, `emacs` might start graphically on `root`'s display. Etc, etc.

Look at using the `sudo:` method from Tramp for editing files using `sudo` from Emacs. For example, to edit `/etc/motd`, do `C-x C-f` and type the path as `/sudo:root@localhost:/etc/motd`.

Answer (score 5):

If I'm understanding your question the following worked just fine for me on CentOS 6.4 which I would expect to be very similar to SLC6:

**initital command**

```
$ sudo sleep 300
^Z
[1]+  Stopped                 sudo sleep 300
```

**background**

```
$ bg
[1]+ sudo sleep 300 &

$ jobs
[1]+  Running                 sudo sleep 300 &

$ ps -eaf|grep sudo
root     25752 25669  0 09:53 pts/0    00:00:00 sudo sleep 300
sam      25755 25669  0 09:53 pts/0    00:00:00 grep sudo
```

**kill job (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>)**

```
$ fg
sudo sleep 300
^C

$ ps -eaf|grep sudo
sam      25758 25669  0 09:53 pts/0    00:00:00 grep sudo
```

**OS Info**

```
$ uname -a
Linux mungr 2.6.32-358.6.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Apr 23 19:29:00 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ cat /etc/redhat-release 
CentOS release 6.4 (Final)
```

Comment: What is strange is that the ^Z after the initial command does nothing.

Answer (score 4):

`CTRL-Z` sends signal `SIGTSTP` to the process.

So the simplest way to do this is:

```
sudo kill -TSTP <pid>
```

from another shell.