# Dropping a process into the background

Tags: shell, process, background-process

If I have started a process, and it spends more time than I anticipated, and I regret not having said `rm foo &` rather than `rm foo`, can I do something to drop it into the background?

Comment: Closely related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/81482/8119

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In pretty much any shell you're likely to be using, you should be able to press control-Z to suspend the process and then use the `bg` command to resume it in the background.

e.g.

```
$ sleep 1000
^Z[1] + Stopped                  sleep 1000

$ bg
[1] sleep 1000&

$ jobs
[1] +  Running                 sleep 1000

$
```

Note that some jobs (e.g. those that ask for user input) will not run in the background and will stop, waiting to be brought back to the foreground (`fg`).

(There *are* shells and situations where this doesn't work, but they tend to be highly specialised - eg embedded systems - or very very old versions of unix).

Comment: Nitpick: The job is not *restarted* in the background, it is resumed. Restarting it would have very weird side effects in many cases. (And no, I'm not picking on you specifically. It's pure coincidence that I felt compelled to comment on two of your answers ;-)

Comment: That's what I get for writing answers while distracted :-)  s/restart/resume/ in the answer.  Thanks!

Comment: Note that the suspension of processes by Ctrl+Z occurs without the intervention of the shell. The signal comes from the kernel's terminal driver.

Answer (score 1):

Another option could be the use of `screen` or `tmux`. You can detach your current session and continue your work later, even from another system. The biggest gain is that the session is automatically detached when the line hangs up. With `tmux` you can even split the screen into panes, switching between them and rearrange the portions with the mouse.

[image: tmux view]